# My time machine is different

Tags: time-machine, monterey

After my upgrade to Monterey my time machine has started to work differently, and I'm not sure is doing backups properly:

- Oldest and latest backups are always "none" on the app and the toolbar
- There's no folders on the disk if I open it in the finder
- My last week's backup is not on the list, but today's backup is. However I can't access it with the arrow buttons inside the time machine
- It's using 197GB on the backups disk, so something is there
- Accessing the disk in the terminal in /Volumes/Backup4 is ok but if I run the `ls`command it says "Operation not permitted", the same with `sudo ls`

Comment: Running Disk Utility first aid on the backup disk... all seems OK.

Comment: What was the previous version of macOS? What is the format of the TM disk - APFS or HFS? Output of `diskutil list` can help (the bits relevant to the TM disk).

Comment: It was Big Sur, and I have an Apple Silicon. But as the new backups didn't showed in the same disk, I've started a new disk (I still have the old one with the previous TM). I've formatted this disk already with Monterey APFS and started a new time machine from scratch. There's no errors on the backup (and the first time it took a few hours). There's no errors with Disk Utility either.

Comment: Output from diskutil list:


`/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +999.8 GB   disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Backup4⁩                 195.3 GB   disk5s2`

Comment: `cd /Volumes/Backup4 && ls` still returns "ls: .: Operation not permitted".

Comment: Now I can browse to yesterday's backup and today's backup but it still says "Oldest backup: none" and "Latest backup: none". And no folders or files if I go to the disk with the finder.

Comment: Re "operation not permitted": Does Terminal have 'full disk access'? https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/

Comment: 1) `ls` is of limited use on TM disk as the APFS volume is full of snapshots - not folders. 2) Finder should show you the snapshots   3) `mount` command will show which snapshots are mounted and where mounted. 4) In Disk Utility use View > Show APFS Snapshots (it will be slow for the TM disk).

Comment: So, the terminal access is fixed, thank you very much. However each folder only contains the new changed files. I can't find a folder with all files, not even my first folder.

All folders have interrupted in the name, although I didn't interrupt any backup:
`drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root  wheel  192 Nov 29 00:58 2021-11-28-222330.interrupted
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root  wheel  192 Dec  1 22:04 2021-12-01-220004.interrupted
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root  wheel  192 Dec  2 18:54 2021-12-02-185246.interrupted
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root  wheel  192 Dec  4 20:04 2021-12-04-195545.inprogress`
And the last one is not in progress.

Comment: On the time machine interface I can only access my lastest (today) backup, all history is gone.

Comment: And in Time Machine preferences it still says Oldest backup none, latest backup none.

Comment: And the finder never showed the snapshots since I upgraded to Monterrey. Anyway I've reformatted the disk and I'm starting again.

Comment: After reformatting and making the first backup it was not showing on the finder. However after I left my computer on all night, it seems to be OK now. Anyway the experience is far worse than with Big Sur. I'm looking at using a second disk backup, at least for my user directory, probably with the open source app restic.net